# Symfony - Restrict QueryParams

Tags: symfony, routes

Is there way to force Symfony throw 404 if there is some extra params ?

For example, I have route /news/ and I want to allow only **date** parameter. So link could exist in this form: **/news/?date=243242**, but I want 404 if user enters following link: **/news/?param=2** ?

Thanks.

(I don't want to check query params in controller, I know I can)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need these to be get params?   You meet your objective buy having them as values in the URL itself e.g.

```
@Route("/news/date/{date}")
```

Slightly different I know - but you can enforce it

Comment: The problem is I have some filters for news list like ,category, date and etc. So there might exist category get parameter or might not. And  all filters are in GET form. Otherwise I would have to define route for all combinations of parameters

Comment: If they are filters - then use the get params - and then you can add validation in your code.  You can still run 404 if the params are not valid.

Comment: I know I can, but like I said I want router to take care of.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care about the extra params anyway? If some nasty user decides to play with the URL directly, your app is not supposed to behave correctly.

Don't bother with all these checks — unless those params somehow affect security.

---

Based on your comment, you want to respond with 404 to get rid of duplicate content in Google. There are several steps you need to take to solve that problem.

If a user enter an extra parameter manually, in no way that would add a page to the Google index. So, if you're having duplicate pages based on different params in the Google index, it means that you have links with those extra params on your site. That's how they end up being indexed.

First thing you could do would be to get rid of those links. Then you could go to the Google Webmaster Tools and manually remove the indexed pages with those extra parameters from the index. If you don't have the problematic links anymore, they won't get to the index again.

If for some reason you can't get rid of those link, go to the Webmaster Tools and consult the URL Parameters section to understand how to add parameters that Google should ignore.

Comment: I'm aware because of duplicate content (Google) :) That's why.

Comment: So, if you're having duplicate pages based on different params in the Google index, it means that you have links with those extra params on your site. That's how they end up being indexed - Bad users can use their sites to link to my sites with these extra params.